# how to write api tests when using subdomain wildcards

Tags: laravel

In my current project I want to use the subdomain as a "team" identifier across the whole API I'm implementing.

However, I strugge with how I can call these routes with the correct parameters from my tests.

Here is a part of my routes file (api)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['domain' => '{team}.' . env('APP_URL', 'localhost:8000')], function () {
    Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
            Route::get('me', 'AuthController@me');
        });
    });
});
```

My tests used to look like this when I did not have the subdomain wildcard in place.

```
/** @test */
public function should_fail_validation_when_no_body_is_sent()
{
  $response = $this->post('/api/auth/login');

  $response->assertStatus(422);
}
```

I could not find any source on how to tackle this for testing.

I've tried

```
$response = $this->post('http://test. ' . env('APP_URL') . '/api/auth/login');
```

which also resulted in a 404

Comment: what value does `env('APP_URL')` have?

Comment: it's `localhost:8000`

Comment: Just tested it locally and it works if I leave off the port, could you try with only `localhost`.

Comment: do you have to run a server individualy for this to work? in my test scenario i do not want to test against my actual server but stay in my test env

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean, I tested it on my local homestead.

Comment: Ok, just tested it again, it works for me even with the port, must've made a mistake the first time. The only thing I could think of is that `env('APP_URL')` isn't set properly, can you dump `env('APP_URL')` in the test and ensure it contains `localhost:8000`

Comment: you are right it actually works - the issue was that when I use `APP_URL` in my routes file I cannot use it in my test env to set my test url (to something like "test.localhost" as it will also change the definition of the routes ...

Comment: As a sidenote, you should never use `env()` outside of configuration files, always use `config()`. `env()` will return null after you run `php artisan config:cache`